# In light of scriptures regarding baptism, does the New Testament teach that it is necessary for one to be saved?

Tags: soteriology, baptism

> 'Peter replied, “**Repent and be baptized, every one of you, in the name of Jesus Christ for the forgiveness of your sins**. And you will receive the gift of the Holy Spirit.'
>   Acts 2:38
>
> What shall we say, then? Shall we go on sinning so that grace may increase? By no means! We are those who have died to sin; how can we live in it any longer? Or don’t you know that all of us who were baptized into Christ Jesus were baptized into his death? **We were therefore buried with him through baptism into death** in order that, just as Christ was raised from the dead through the glory of the Father, we too may live a new life. For if we have been united with him in a death like his, we will certainly also be united with him in a resurrection like his. For we know that our old self was crucified with him so that the body ruled by sin might be done away with, that we should no longer be slaves to sin." Romans 6:1-6
>
> "He said to them, “Go into all the world and preach the gospel to all creation. **Whoever believes and is baptized will be saved**, but whoever does not believe will be condemned." Mark 16:15,16
>
> "Then Jesus came to them and said, “All authority in heaven and on earth has been given to me. Therefore **go and make disciples of all nations, baptizing them in the name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit**, and teaching them to obey everything I have commanded you. And surely I am with you always, to the very end of the age.” Matthew 28:18-20

Do these and other 'baptism' passages teach that baptism in water (immersion) is necessary for one to be saved?

Comment: This question is probably a better fit for [Christianity.SE] as it is asking about Christian theology rather than the historical context of any particular text.

Comment: Yes, Christianity would be a better fit, however, this would likely be closed as a duplicate due to the answers already provided:
http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/36970
http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/335

Answer (score 1):

I had to research this question extensively as my wife came from a Churches of Christ background, which places a massive emphasis on baptism-as-salvation.

This is a contentious question, and one which many different conclusions may be arrived at biblically. Unfortunately, the scriptures are not exactly straightforward on the matter, and so there's a danger of prooftexting... playing 'Bible Trumps' between different verses doesn't really settle it, and is a terrible way to do exegesis in the first place. Depending on your exact view of how Biblical revelation works, there are several complications, which I shall mention the ones I consider key:

### Complications

**- Matthew 28:18-20 doesn't say Baptism is the thing that saves**. Yes it's a command, yes it's done as part of the disciple-making process, but no this verse doesn't help us determine its relationship to salvation.

**- Mark 16:9-20 aren't in the earliest manuscripts of Mark** ([link](http://www.bible-researcher.com/endmark.html)). Depending on your view of Biblical revelation, this may or may not be a big deal. The later church fathers accepted these inserted verses, and so this may be enough for you. But the original author almost certainly did not write them, and so I wouldn't dare use them as a key justification for a doctrinal issue.

**- Therefore, none of the Gospels as originally penned link Baptism with salvation... indeed, Jesus himself certainly never does.** Matthew makes a mention of its link with discipleship (above), but Mark, Luke and John don't cover it at all, and rarely even use the word except for in connection with John the Baptist. Indeed, John repeatedly quotes Jesus talking about salvation but always connects it with faith with no mention of baptism.

**- Portions of Acts, Romans and other writings do talk about salvation coming via baptism (as you've highlighted), but there are verses which imply salvation comes only by faith**:

> "For by grace **you have been saved through faith**; and that not of yourselves, it is the gift of God" (Eph 2:8)
>
> "if you confess with your mouth Jesus as Lord, and believe in your heart that God raised Him from the dead, y**ou will be saved**" (Rom 10:9)
>
> "For God so loved the world that He gave His only son, so that **whoever believes in him shall not perish but have everlasting life**." (John 3:15-16)
>
> "**He who believes in the Son has eternal life**; but he who does not obey the Son will not see life, but the wrath of God abides on him." (John 3:36)

**- The Holy Spirit only dwells in clean vessels, and Cornelius was such a vessel pre-Baptism**: Acts 10:44 details the Holy Spirit coming upon Cornelius and his household ahead of their Baptism. Peter reinforces the point in Acts 15:6-11:

> “Brothers, you know that some time ago God made a choice among you that the Gentiles might hear from my lips the message of the gospel and believe. God, who knows the heart, **showed that he accepted them by giving the Holy Spirit to them, just as he did to us**. He did not discriminate between us and them, for **he purified their hearts by faith**. Now then, why do you try to test God by putting on the necks of Gentiles a yoke that neither we nor our ancestors have been able to bear? No! We believe it is **through the grace of our Lord Jesus that we are saved, just as they are**.”

Consider this alongside:

> "And you also were included in Christ when you heard the message of truth, the gospel of your salvation. **When you believed, you were marked in him with a seal, the promised Holy Spirit, who is a deposit guaranteeing our inheritance** until the redemption of those who are God’s possession—to the praise of his glory." (Eph 1:13-14)

People have sought to explain this event away in many forms, but regardless of whether the Cornelius episode was a special 'sign', the Apostles certainly recognised it as a mark which guarantees the inheritance of a believer. Peter says God gave the household the Holy Spirit "just as he did to us", in other words just as He did in Acts chapter 1, to the Apostles in the upper room.

---

### Discussion

Again, we must be very careful to avoid prooftexting - 'Bible Trumps' is not an appropriate way to handle the Word of God, as if we could pit it against itself. Taking one verse at the expense of another is the best way to fail at biblical interpretation.

Is Baptism under-emphasised in mainstream churches today? Frequently, **yes**. The New Testament paints it as nothing less than the *normative* means through which any man or woman places their faith in Christ. Again and again we find it synonymous with 'salvation', because all Christians were immediately baptised, and this is indeed the way things were both intended and practised from the very beginning of the church. Obedience to the command of Baptism is biblical and right, as your highlighted passages and others make clear.

However, in light of the many other passages (indeed, the major Biblical meta-narrative) about salvation in God coming through faith alone, can we insist that water baptism is 'necessary' for salvation? Probably not. 1 Peter 3:21 is perhaps the most helpful verse here: "this water symbolizes baptism that now saves you also--**not the removal of dirt from the body but the pledge of a clear conscience toward God.** It saves you by the resurrection of Jesus Christ". Thus, Baptism was/is salvific only where it is the expression of a pledge of a clear conscience towards God, in this fashion.

Over the centuries various kinds of Christians have adjusted their Baptism practises considerably for all kinds of reasons... yet today it's still normative for pretty much all Christians to be baptised at some point in their discipleship journey. Some churches have normalised a 'pledge' of clear conscience as the salvific experience, with Baptism to follow soon thereafter. Whilst this is (biblically) not the best way to do things, that doesn't necessarily mean it's ineffective. Some Christians undergo such a 'pledge' and then walk away from their faith, but then again others undergo baptism and then do the same. From personal experience I'd say it's difficult to demonstrate that one or the other produces a 'salvation' that is more or less effective.

From the earliest centuries new Christian initiates went through 'catechism' classes leading them towards Baptism. Some Christian-identifying individuals have claimed salvation from a Baptism-event alone, without any ongoing experience of faith. Many later traditions had plagues of Christians who were 'baptised' at an early stage later expressing no belief whatsoever, and so have taken more cautious approaches to ensuring Christians are mature enough to take on the gravity of the situation first.

---

### Conclusion

These and other scriptures are thus clear that Baptism is a necessary part of discipleship, and the thing anybody should do upon realising their need of Christ. It is the means by which they publicly declare that faith in Him, and is a wonderful hallmark they can look back on, which identifies themselves strongly with Christ and bears witness to their salvation.

However, as an individual from a tradition which does not traditionally hold baptism-as-salvation, I have had the privilege of witnessing many other Cornelius's - many individuals with clear and radiant expressions of the Holy Spirit on them ahead of their Baptism. Common sense allows us to marry up such real-world works of God to confirm the scriptures as He has provided them to us.

Some might argue that based on some verses, Baptism must enter one into the Kingdom in a way which another Pledge can't... but if that's not a demonstrable truth then it's one to be handled carefully. In my experience, just as many Baptised Christians walk away from their faith as those who only ever had a 'pledge', and so practically it's difficult to justify saying that one was 'saved' in their experience and the other wasn't. Constructing a non-practical theology of life is pretty useless to everybody, especially ourselves.

Thus I would answer your question by saying Baptism should still be **normative** as the salvation point for new Christians, but can occasionally come afterwards - and at the end of the day as the Apostles and Christ himself all teach, their salvation comes by faith, one way or another.

Answer (score -1):

From everything the Scriptures state, baptism is not necessary to salvation--BUT for anyone who is saved, it is something that they would do in obedience.

The fundamental text for this is [Acts 16:31](http://biblehub.com/acts/16-31.htm), where the jailer in Philippi was persuaded to ask "What must I do to be saved?" Paul and Silas do not say "Believe and be baptized," but it is obvious that if one is to be obedient, one will seek baptism as quickly as possible. And I do mean "As quickly as possible." While the jailer took the time to wash Paul and Silas's wounds, he sought baptism even before he brought them to his house and fed them.

Baptism is obedience--but a person who believes is saved.

Comment: Justin, I think you accidentally wrote "....belief is not necessary to salvation," I think you probably meant to say, "baptism is not necessary to salvation." Thanks, but I really wanted if one must be baptized BEFORE he would be saved.

Comment: I agree with the conclusion, but don't understand how you got there based on that passage alone - can you please have a re-read of your answer? Not my dv for the record

Comment: Re-reading the answer ... yes, you're correct. I used some "mental shorthand" to come to my conclusion. Thank you for pointing this out--I'll expand on how I got there.

Comment: Dale, I could extend my answer, but I would be duplicating a lot of Steve Taylor's answer--and frankly, while I could say what he said again, I couldn't say it better. I've put a +1 on his answer, as it is vastly superior to mine.

Answer (score -1):

It is sad that this question even comes up.  When looking at the passages referred to (And I will limit myself to Romans 6 and 1 Peter), there are things happening in baptism that happen nowhere else.
1. Burial with Christ (Laying off the old) is one of the things that can happen only in baptism (immersion, to be exact).  It is a re-enactment of the burial of Christ
2. Raised with Christ (putting on the new) also only happens in baptism, nowhere else.
3. Raised in newness of life cannot be done unless one is "buried" with Christ (again, something taking place only in the baptism, immersion).
God does these things in baptism which happen at no other phase in the conversion process.  It is sad when we read the first public telling of the Gospel (Acts 2) and we still argue about the necessity of baptism.
It's not the "water" (Which is often used as a red herring argument by those who do not believe in the necessity of baptism for salvation) that makes the difference!  The acting of God in that process are what does matter, however. 
In Acts we see the first response, "What must we do...?" and the reply, "...be baptized for the forgiveness of sin..." which seems so clear!
Forgiveness of sin takes place in baptism (That IS what the text says, no matter how you want to interpret it).
Peter speaks of water as the 'saving agent' when he uses the flood as an illustration.  No one questions the fact that it was neither water nor ark saved, but God by use of that agent took care of the salvation process.
It was not until late 2nd, early 3rd century that questions started around the METHOD of baptism (Deathbed situations), but the necessity was not questioned until relatively late in history.
One of the best books on Baptism and it's history is written by G. George Beasley-Murray.  And yet, in the end, he prefers his own "group's" practice, in spite of all the evidence he has presented...
Now, if a certain religious group wants to have their own thoughts on baptism (purpose, necessity etc.) that is one thing.  But what I appreciate about George Beasley-Murray's book is that he never argues against the fact that the Scriptures do teach it's necessity.  At one place he even write, that the question was unheard of in the early Church (P. 166 in my copy).  It would have been seen as a ridiculous question.  Baptism was held as the ONLY way to become part of the community of the believers.  Not, as too many would have it today, A way, just as good as other ways...